# How i can make it word,if click the img , insert date into mysql.

Tags: mysql, click

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("a.01").click(function({
      $.post( "test.php" );
 }
 ))
 })
</script>
<div><a class="01" href='test.php'><img src="../photo/test.jpg" width="100"></a></div>
```

How i can make it word,if click the img , insert date into mysql. 
THX..

Comment: Make it *work*? This is ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basicly how ajax works. I don't know which data you wan't to send with ajax to php.
Here it's `innerHTML` of element

HTML:

```
<div id="test" onclick="return send();">
Click
</div>
```

JS.:

```
function send() {

var x = document.getElementById("test").innerHTML;

$.post(
        'insertData.php', 
        {
            firstname : x
        },

        function(data){

            if(data == 'Hello World'){
               alert('done');
            }
            else
            {
            alert('there was an error');
            }

        },

        'text'
     );
        }

        return false; // keeps on the same page
});
```

}

PHP

```
<?php
//MYSQL REQUEST HERE

echo 'Hello World';

?>
```